# Background Element Goes Over Body Element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a background element with the blur effect (seen here)

```css
.background-image {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image: url('bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  height: 800px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100; 
}
```

However, when I put it in my HTML:

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div>
        <div class="background-image"></div>

            <div class="homestrip">
                <!-- rest of stuff goes here -->
```

the background overlaps everything. I can't see my body elements and no matter where I move the background-image element the rest of my stuff isn't visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the background element negative [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to place it under it's parent.

```css
.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200');
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  height: 800px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image">
</div>

<h1>Text over image</h1>
```

A better option is to use a pseudo element instead of markup:

```css
body::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  height: 800px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  content: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200');
}

body {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text over image</h1>
```